# Pass parameters to XSP on MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop, xsp

Is there a way to pass parameters to XSP from Monodevelop (ASP.NET debug session) ?

I'm using Monodevelop 5.9.6/mono 4.0.4 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm trying to set root folder of XSP: ***--root PATH*** from [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jaunty/man1/fastcgi-mono-server.1.html).

I know I could use xsp.exe.config to do that. However, that would mean to change the xsp user-wide configuration (since, IMHK, xsp.exe.config should be placed next to the xsp.exe and it is then shared for all invocation of xsp.exe). Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Work around:**

I didn't use the inbuilt xsp invocation and directly debug it from Monodevelop with the according parameters.